# Refresh content in a for loop using jquery in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am creating a website that allows users to search for a list of papers. Once a list of papers is returned, the user can click "like" or "dislike" to one or more papers. The like count should dynamically update as the user click the like button.

I am using jquery to handle the dynamic update of the like count.  However, I am not sure how to tell the `success` function in the ajax WHICH id to update. The reason is that the `id` is generated on the fly, and it is determined by which papers are returned as search results to the user.

So far, I have the following  in the template:

```
{% for result in results %}
 <li >
{{ result.title}},
<a href="#" class="like_button" data-pid="{{ result.pk }}"> <span class="like_span fa fa-thumbs-up"></span> </a>

 <strong id="like_count_{{ result.pk }}">{{result.likes}} </strong> 
</li> 
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, i specify the id of the part where I want the dynamic update to happen as `"like_count_{{ result.pk }}"`.  I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

The jquery part looks like this:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".like_button").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {'pk': $(this).data('pid'),
                           'liked': $("span").hasClass('fa fa-thumbs-up') },
                    url: "{% url 'search:paperpreference' %}",
                    success: function(response) {
                        var pk  = $(this).data('pid');
                        $(?????).html(response.likes )
                    },
                    error: function(response, error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
            });
          });
    </script>
```

Simply put, I don't know how can i specify the ????? part such that when success, the new like count is only updated to that specific paper, not the first paper in the loop.

The views.py has the following so far:

```
def paperpreference(request):
   # if request.method == "GET":
    pid = request.GET['pk']
    paper = Paper.objects.get(pk=pid)
    likes = paper.likes + 1
    paper.likes = likes
    paper.save()
    data = {'likes': paper.likes}

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I am new to Jquery, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: $("#like_count_" + pk)?

Comment: tried that but unfortunately that doesn't work..

Comment: add a `console.log(pk)` statement and `console.log("#like_count_" + pk)`. And then debug your page, in your console, type `$("#like_count_2")` yourself to see the result. Or set a breakpoint in your success function and inspect your variables directly there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I encountered this error in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: pk is not defined`. So apparently, the `pk` value is not passed

Comment: Sorry let me clarify - if i leave `var pk  = $(this).data('pid');` in the success function, `#like_count_undefined` is printed in the console.When I remove `var pk  = $(this).data('pid');` in the success function, I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: pk is not defined`

Comment: you should define `var pk = $(this).data('pid')` before your line `$.ajax...` and just use `pk` both in the `data` object and in the success function. Note sure what is `$(this)` inside of `$.ajax()`

Comment: Moving the `var pk = ...` to before `$.ajax` works! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to suggestions by @dirkgroten, the like count can now be dynamically updated by the following jquery function. The trick is to move the pk declaration to before the ajax.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".like_button").click(function(){
                var pk = $(this).data('pid')
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {'pk': pk,
                           'liked': $("span").hasClass('fa fa-thumbs-up') },
                    url: "{% url 'search:paperpreference' %}",
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#like_count_"+ pk).html(response.likes )
                    },
                    error: function(response, error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
            });
          });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

another option is return the id from the server.

```
def paperpreference(request):
   # if request.method == "GET":
    pid = request.GET['pk']
    paper = Paper.objects.get(pk=pid)
    likes = paper.likes + 1
    paper.likes = likes
    paper.save()
    data = {'likes': paper.likes,'pid':pid}

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".like_button").click(function(){
                var pk = $(this).data('pid')
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {'pk': pk,
                           'liked': $("span").hasClass('fa fa-thumbs-up') },
                    url: "{% url 'search:paperpreference' %}",
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#like_count_"+ response.pid).html(response.likes )
                    },
                    error: function(response, error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
            });
          });
    </script>
```

Comment: yeah that's one option i haven't thought of!